# Filling all colors using CSS/js from a SVG

Tags: css, svg, image-manipulation

I am trying to set a fill color of a shape from an external svg that I link to inside an HTML document, so I'm using CSS/JS to style.

I'm currently only able to get a stroke to work, but that the fill seems to be overridden. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<svg style="fill:green" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
<!--        <image id="one" xlink:href="sears/alt1/body/willis-body.svg#body-windows-left" x="54.5" y="338"/>-->
<use style="fill:orange" class="icon" xlink:href="sears/alt1/body/willis-body.svg#body-windows-left" transform="translate(50 50)"/>
<use style="fill:orange" class="icon" xlink:href="sears/alt1/body/willis-body.svg#body-windows-left" transform="translate(350 50)"/>
</svg>

<style>
/*
    #svg {
        fill: none;
    }
*/


    use.icon:hover {
        stroke: teal;
        width: 100px;
        fill: orange !imporant;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to use  `<use>` its only taking copy of your `<circle>` obj as you see the code snippet you can style the `<circle>` and in the same time it will effect the `<use>`

```css
#circle:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <circle id="circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="150"/>
  <use href="#circle" x="10"  fill="red" transform="translate(350 50)"/>
  <use href="#circle" x="10"  fill="yellow" transform="translate(700 50)"/>
</svg>
```

and if you want to style the `<use>`

```css
/* #circle:hover {
  fill: blue;
} */

.new:hover {
  fill: green;
}

.new2:hover {
  fill: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" id="tr">
  <circle id="circle" cx="150" cy="150" r="150"/>
  <use href="#circle" x="10"  class="new"fill="red" transform="translate(350 50)"/>
  <use href="#circle" x="10"  class="new2" fill="yellow" transform="translate(700 50)"/>
</svg>
```